# .ipynb Notebook more than 5 MB not opening on Jupyter Notebook python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, large-files

I am trying to open my old notebook that I made last week. The size of the notebook is 7 MB. When I try to open it, it gives a pop up saying: "error loading notebook" and it closes. I am attaching a screenshot as well.

[image]

I checked the console while it was trying to open and here is the log of it:

[image]

I was able to open this yesterday without any problem. I checked by opening this notebook on visual studio code just to make sure there is nothing wrong with the notebook and it was opening. This problem is there only for files that are heavy or more than 5 MB.

Does anyone know what can be the issue?